# Collider class using some kind of visitor pattern

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to create a Collider class which will process collisions between different classes of the same base. One restriction is that I want these classes know nothing about each other, now they depend on Base and Collider classes only. Here is my code:

collidees.h

```
#pragma once

#include "collider.h"

#define ALLOW_COLLIDER_VISIT                                        \
    virtual void visit(Collider& c) override { c.collide(*this); }; \
    virtual void visit(Collider& c, Base& other) override { c.collide(*this, other); };

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void visit(Collider& c)              = 0;
    virtual void visit(Collider& c, Base& other) = 0;
};

struct A : Base {
    ALLOW_COLLIDER_VISIT;
};

struct B : Base {
    ALLOW_COLLIDER_VISIT;
};

struct C : Base {
    ALLOW_COLLIDER_VISIT;
};
```

collider.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#define ADD_REVERSE_COLLISION(A, B)                    \
    template<>                                         \
    inline void Collider::performCollision(B& b, A& a) \
    {                                                  \
        performCollision(a, b);                        \
    }

#define CALL_COLLIDER_FOR(CLASS) \
    void collide(CLASS& a) { collider.performCollision<T, CLASS>(static_cast<T&>(base), a); }

struct Base;
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;
struct Collider;

struct HelperBase {
    HelperBase(Base& base_, Collider& collider_) : base { base_ }, collider { collider_ } {}
    virtual ~HelperBase() = default;

    virtual void collide(A& base) = 0;
    virtual void collide(B& base) = 0;
    virtual void collide(C& base) = 0;

    Base&     base;
    Collider& collider;
};

template<typename T>
struct Helper;

struct Collider {
    template<typename T>
    void collide(T& t) {
        if (helper) {
            helper->collide(t);
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void collide(T& t, Base& other) {
        helper = std::make_unique<Helper<T>>(t, *this);
        callOtherToVisit(other);
    }

    void callOtherToVisit(Base& other);

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void performCollision(T1& first, T2& second) {
        std::cout << "No collision handler\n";
    }

    std::unique_ptr<HelperBase> helper = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
struct Helper : HelperBase {
    Helper(T& base, Collider& c) : HelperBase { base, c } {}

    CALL_COLLIDER_FOR(A);
    CALL_COLLIDER_FOR(B);
    CALL_COLLIDER_FOR(C);
};

template<>
inline void Collider::performCollision(A& a, B& b) {
    std::cout << "Colliding a and b\n";
}
ADD_REVERSE_COLLISION(A, B);

template<>
inline void Collider::performCollision(B& b1, B& b2) {
    std::cout << "Colliding b1 and b2\n";
}

template<>
inline void Collider::performCollision(A& a, C& c) {
    std::cout << "Colliding a and c\n";
}
ADD_REVERSE_COLLISION(A, C);

template<>
inline void Collider::performCollision(B& b, C& c) {
    std::cout << "Colliding b and c\n";
}
ADD_REVERSE_COLLISION(B, C);
```

collider.cpp

```
#include "collider.h"
#include "collidees.h"

void Collider::callOtherToVisit(Base& other)
{
    other.visit(*this);
}
```

main.cpp - driver code

```
#include "collidees.h"
#include "collider.h"

int main()
{
    Collider collider;

    auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
    auto b = std::make_unique<B>();
    auto c = std::make_unique<C>();

    a->visit(collider, *b);
    a->visit(collider, *c);
    c->visit(collider, *b);
    c->visit(collider, *a);
    b->visit(collider, *a);

    return 0;
}
```

I suppose there are some disadvantages of this code:

1. It's quite complicated; adding a new collidee entails adding code in multiple places;
2. There is one static_cast instead of true dispatching (although, I suppose it is safe);
3. It's possible to call `void visit(Collider& c)` yourself, which is meaningless;
4. Class `Helper` stores reference to the object that can be easily deleted, which causes storing of dangling reference.

(Feel free to add other drawbacks in comments)

I would be glad to see any suggestions and improvements (or even your versions of this code).

**UPDATE:** Answers to comments:

- I assume collision detection as a separate step. At least in my case it is enough to add shape (or even just a rect) data to base class and find intersections of two objects, so derivatives still know nothing about each other.
- Virtual and override keywords in method declaration - it's just an inattention.
- Const correctness - again, I was focused on main problem, and missed it, although, yes, the `performCollision` method may modify arguments, so they cann't be const.

Anyway, thanks for replies. I think I will try to correct my code according to user673679's suggestions and then try to incorporate `std::variant` and `std::visit` as both commenters mentioned. I'll wait a little bit more for others and then aacept an answer.

Comment: How can you test for collision between objects of two different types, if they don't know about each other?  If the `Collider` class has the actual work, and thus knows about all the different types involved, why do to collidable classes need a virtual visit function at all?

Comment: That is, why would it not work like `std::visit`?  I understand that this doesn't have a two-argument form, but I mean work in the same manner.  The Collider has functions with signatures for all the classes it can handle, so having a master list as part of Collider is not out of the question.

Comment: Correction:  [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) *does* take multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `const` correctness:

There are a *lot* of `const`s missing.

- None of the member functions modify member data (on the shape classes, or the helpers), so they should all be marked `const`. e.g. `virtual void visit(Collider& c) const = 0;`
- None of the function arguments passed by reference (to the shape classes or helpers) are modified, so they should be passed by `const&` instead. e.g. `virtual void collide(A const& base) = 0;`

(Note: I guess if you intended to implement collision response (i.e. modify the objects) inside the `performCollision` calls, then you'd have to leave things non-const. Instead, I'd suggest returning enough information (e.g. as a `std::optional<CollisionData>`) to resolve the collision as a separate step later on. This is more flexible (e.g. it allows you to process collisions in groups for optimization or accuracy)).

---

### unnecessary allocation:

We don't need to store the `Helper` in a `unique_ptr`. Rather than storing a reference to the `Base` class in `HelperBase`, we can store a reference to the template class in the template `Helper` class, e.g.:

```
template<class T>
struct Helper: HelperBase
{
    Helper(T const& t): t(t) { }

    T const& t;

    ...
};
```

Since `Helper` now preserves the type of the first argument we no longer need the `static_cast`.

Then we can create a `Helper` of the relevant type directly in the shape class `visit` functions, e.g:

```
struct A : Base
{
    void visit(Shape const& other) const override
    {
        auto helper = Helper<A>(*this);
        other.visit(helper);
    }

    void visit(HelperBase const& helper) const override
    {
        helper.collide(*this);
    }
};
```

This avoids the heap allocation, and means we don't actually need the `Collider` class. :)

We could pass the shape class type to the `ALLOW_COLLIDER_VISIT` macro, or add a `make_helper<T>(*this)` function so that we didn't have to.

---

### unnecessary template specialization:

We don't need to use template specialization for the collision functions:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void performCollision(T1& first, T2& second) ...
```

We can use simple overloading:

```
void performCollision(A const& , A const& ) { std::cout << "(A, A)\n"; }
void performCollision(B const& , B const& ) { std::cout << "(B, B)\n"; }
void performCollision(C const& , C const& ) { std::cout << "(C, C)\n"; }
void performCollision(A const& , B const& ) { std::cout << "(A, B)\n"; }
... etc.
```

---

### example:

To illustrate the points above:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

void collide(A const& , A const& ) { std::cout << "(A, A)\n"; }
void collide(B const& , B const& ) { std::cout << "(B, B)\n"; }
void collide(C const& , C const& ) { std::cout << "(C, C)\n"; }
void collide(A const& , B const& ) { std::cout << "(A, B)\n"; }
void collide(B const& , A const& ) { std::cout << "(B, A)\n"; }
void collide(A const& , C const& ) { std::cout << "(A, C)\n"; }
void collide(C const& , A const& ) { std::cout << "(C, A)\n"; }
void collide(C const& , B const& ) { std::cout << "(C, B)\n"; }
void collide(B const& , C const& ) { std::cout << "(B, C)\n"; }

struct CollisionDispatcherBase
{
    virtual void collide(A const& other) const = 0;
    virtual void collide(B const& other) const = 0;
    virtual void collide(C const& other) const = 0;
};

template<class T>
struct CollisionDispatcher : CollisionDispatcherBase
{
    CollisionDispatcher(T const& t): t(t) { }

    T const& t;

    void collide(A const& other) const override { ::collide(t, other); };
    void collide(B const& other) const override { ::collide(t, other); };
    void collide(C const& other) const override { ::collide(t, other); };
};

struct Shape
{
    virtual ~Shape() {}

    virtual void visit(Shape const& other) const = 0;
    virtual void visit(CollisionDispatcherBase const& c) const = 0;
};

struct A : Shape
{
    void visit(Shape const& other) const override { auto c = CollisionDispatcher<A>{ *this }; other.visit(c); }
    void visit(CollisionDispatcherBase const& c) const override { c.collide(*this); }
};

struct B : Shape
{
    void visit(Shape const& other) const override { auto c = CollisionDispatcher<B>{ *this }; other.visit(c); }
    void visit(CollisionDispatcherBase const& c) const override { c.collide(*this); }
};

struct C : Shape
{
    void visit(Shape const& other) const override { auto c = CollisionDispatcher<C>{ *this }; other.visit(c); }
    void visit(CollisionDispatcherBase const& c) const override { c.collide(*this); }
};

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto colliders = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>();
    colliders.push_back(std::make_unique<A>());
    colliders.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
    colliders.push_back(std::make_unique<C>());
    
    for (auto i = std::size_t{ 0 }; i != colliders.size() - 1; ++i)
        for (auto j = i + 1; j != colliders.size(); ++j)
            colliders[i]->visit(*colliders[j]);
}
```

---

### use std::variant instead?

If the version of C++ you're using supports `std::variant`, we can ditch inheritance  and use `std::visit` to do the double dispatch for us:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct A { };
struct B { };
struct C { };

struct collide_visitor
{
    void operator()(A const& , A const& ) const { std::cout << "(A, A)\n"; }
    void operator()(B const& , B const& ) const { std::cout << "(B, B)\n"; }
    void operator()(C const& , C const& ) const { std::cout << "(C, C)\n"; }
    void operator()(A const& , B const& ) const { std::cout << "(A, B)\n"; }
    void operator()(B const& , A const& ) const { std::cout << "(B, A)\n"; }
    void operator()(A const& , C const& ) const { std::cout << "(A, C)\n"; }
    void operator()(C const& , A const& ) const { std::cout << "(C, A)\n"; }
    void operator()(C const& , B const& ) const { std::cout << "(C, B)\n"; }
    void operator()(B const& , C const& ) const { std::cout << "(B, C)\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    using collider = std::variant<A, B, C>;

    auto colliders = std::vector<collider>();
    colliders.push_back(A{});
    colliders.push_back(B{});
    colliders.push_back(C{});

    for (auto i = std::size_t{ 0 }; i != colliders.size() - 1; ++i)
        for (auto j = i + 1; j != colliders.size(); ++j)
            std::visit(collide_visitor{}, colliders[i], colliders[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one coding tip:

`virtual void visit(Collider& c) override`

[Use *exactly one of* `virtual` or `override`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override).  That is, you don't repeat the `virtual` on the overrides.